# Azure Pipelines: Wait for the triggered pipeline to finish (Chain Builds Awaiter)

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a pipeline that triggers parallel build using [`Parallel Builds tasks`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=kneradovsky.viko-build-tasks) and is supposed to wait till all the parallel builds have completed. These parallel builds run for a very long time (like 3 to 3.5 days). So far the **Parallel Builds Task** starts the build as expected and waits for `1d 23h 22m`, but fails after that. I am unable to see the logs, it shows as failed but does not allow to click on the task to check the logs or to download.

[image]

The `TimeOut` Variable for the task is 0 which indicates infinite timeout, but since every time it is failing after same amount of time I think it is running out of time.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: I am testing this task. But since this timeout takes almost 48h, you may have to wait for a while. 
During this time, you can try to manually set a sufficiently large timeout value, and then check if the same restriction still exists.
You could also share the task definition.

Comment: Thanks. I will try the specific amount of time.

Comment: From the [extension source code](https://github.com/kneradovsky/viko-vsts-extensions/blob/master/Tasks/ChainBuildsAwaiter/awaitbuilds.ts#L188), it seems that the  value of **"Seconds to sleep between queue check iterations"** could affect the running time. After my test, if the value becomes larger, the running time will also increase. You could try to expand this value and check the result. By the way, can you see some error messages from the whole build?

Comment: I don't see any error message, even though it says it failed i am not able to click on the task to get the log. I tried to give a specific time for timeout that did not make any difference. Will try the interval for sleep time. Thanks

Comment: In my opinion, this situation is really strange(no any error log). From my test, I could see this error:`Error: read ECONNRESET at exports._errnoException` . You could try the sleep time.